# What are the preprocessing steps for text classification after removing stopwords?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I am working on an NLP project where I have text that I need to categorize based on topics (The data is 2 columns, text and topic).

Something that I am stuck on now is the preprocessing part. What are the steps and in what order?

So far, what I have done is remove stopwords.

I have heard of TFIDF, Count Vectorizer, BOW, Tokenization, and Lemmatization/Stemming. However, I am confused about when to use them and in what order. Could someone please explain what can I do after removing stopwords? And do I need to one-hot encode the labels (topics) in order to pass it on to the model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track as far as preprocessing techniques are considered. Generally this order is followed :

1. **Lowercase** the text if your problem statement allows. In this case you can go ahead and do it.
2. **Tokenize** the text. This can be sentence level or word level.
3. **Lemmatize/Stemming** the tokens. This reduces the tokens to their base level.
4. Remove the following :- **stops words, punctuation marks, hyperlinks, smileys, email ids** etc. Basically anything that is not needed for classification.
5. Vectorize the text using **BOW** or **TFIDF** approach.

**Cheers!**

Comment: Thank you! The vectorized text in step 5 is what will be passed on to the model, is that correct? 
Also, could you tell me why do we tokenize before stemming and removing stopwords?

Comment: Yes the vectorized data is paased on to the model as ML models cannot work with categorical/string/text data and need to be vectorized. 
Stemming/Lemmatization and Stop Word Removal are word level techniques that work on words/tokens and not on paragraphs. Hence the need to tokenize!